# Importar archivo CSV desde Facebook marketing API

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-api

He generado las estadisticas de mis campañas de **Facebook** con la [API de Marketing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.9) y [php ads sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk), logro obtener acceso a mi reporte y desde el navegador lo puedo descargar entrando a una url como esta:

> www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id=REPORT_ID&format=csv&access_token=TOKEN

```
$fileName = "campaign_insights.csv";
$graph_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id='.$report_run.'&format=csv&access_token='.$access_token;

$path = "campaign_insights.csv";

set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
var_dump($result); //siempre responde false
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Mi problema esta en cuando intento guardar ese archivo generado (csv) directamente en mi servidor, he intentado hacerlo con `cURL`, `file_get_contents` pero no he logrado tener éxito, el `cURL` me responde *empty* y `file_get_contents` **Facebook** no lo permite, alguna idea de como podría hacer para guardar dicho archivo en mi servidor?

Gracias.

**UPDATE:**

La solución esta mas abajo.

Comment: Deberías agregar el código con el que estás intentando descargarlo.

Comment: @federhico tienes razón, gracias! Ya lo he agregado.

Comment: Deberías poner la solución a la que llegaste como respuesta, y no en la misma pregunta. Saludos @JoseFlores

Comment: Gracias @AdrianaHernández ya modifique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he logrado dar con la solución, lo dejo acá por si le es útil a otra persona:

Despues de algunas pruebas me di cuenta que el curl respondia que mi navegador esta desactualizado.

Lo actualice con:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
));
```

el código completo quedaría asi:

```
$fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Haciendo esto el problema quedo totalmente solucionado.

Con ayuda de [Chin Leung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5556440/chin-leung) de Stackoverflow en ingles.